# "The binary you uploaded was invalid. the file was not a valid zip file" Error message uploading app to iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload an iPhone app binary to iTunesConnect and keep getting the following error message "The binary you upload was invalid. the file was not a valid zip file". I had an app upload ok recently but this app is having problems. So after a while I carefully went through the following steps trying to make sure everything was ok. Any help is appreciated.

The steps:

1. renamed the project
   (Project->Rename... enter name into
   Rename project to:) to release name
   making sure the name has no spaces.
2. Cleaned project
3. Make sure
           references in build setting reflect
           new app name
4. Create new app ID
       matching project name in iPhone
       Provisioning Portal
5. Destroyed old
       developer and distributer
       provisioning profiles in
       Provisioning Portal, in XCode and on
       iPhone.
6. Create new development
       provisioning profile using new app
       name.
7. Install development
       provisioning profile into XCode 8)
       Build (Release) for iPhone OS 3.1.3
       (highest my phone will upgrade to,
       I'm assuming current released
       version)
8. > > Builds, Installs and Runs on actual 
   > >     iPhone: To me this implys App    and
   > >     developer ID's are OK.
9. Create a distributor provisioning profile
   using existing Distributer ID.
10. Install distributer ID into XCode
11. Clean
12. Checked that "Code
         Signing Identity" and "Any iPhone OS
         Device" lines in Build settings are
         set to Distributor ID
13. Build for
         release for OS 3.1.3
14. Check Build
         results to make sure code is signed
         with Distributor Profile
15. Reveal
         .app file and compress (alt click >
         Compress "appName.app")
16. Upload
         to iTunes connect

    > > Gives "The binary you uploaded was invalid. The file was not a
    > >     valid zip file"

Comment: First thing to do is to see if you can use a ZIP tool to browse the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some additional steps I try: Quit Xcode after clean (or clean all) then delete the Build folder. I don't "Build and Go", just "Build". The AppName.app is generally in the "App Store" folder (or whatever you name your build configuration for App Store release. I right click only that AppName.app file and choose "Compress" in the Finder.

You could also try uploading it with Safari.

It seems like your problem isn't with the provisioning profiles, but with the way the file is being zipped (or maybe uploaded). Try repeating that part, changing details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. It turned out the problem was to do with the fact my project folder was on an ntfs HD. As an experiment I copied it onto my macs HD and it worked perfectly. I don't really understand why this is.

Comment: It may be simply that the file could not be uploaded reliably from the NTFS drive.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS (New Technology File System) is a windows format. You may like to read this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS

Now if you will have a NTFS format iTunes will not recognize that format. And iTunes will support or recognize mac extended versions.

So try not to use NTFS or FAT format for ziping up the projects.

Regards

Rajeev

Comment: A zip file doesn't "care" what "file system" is used to contain it.  It's a sequence of bytes with a (relatively) well-defined format, independent of file system.  It is possible that the OP somehow created a (misnamed) "zip" file in Microsoft's proprietary archive format, but that would take some extra effort on his part.